# How can I check a variable if contains numbers 0 to 9 and characters a to z?

Tags: php, numbers, contains

I would like to know how can I check if a variable contains numbers 0 to 9 and characters a to z, like that:

```
 if($string contains numbers[0-9] and characters[a-z])
 {
  echo "true";
} else {echo "false";}
```

Comment: duplicate of many many questions

Comment: search for PHP regular expression syntax and examples

Answer (score 4):

You can use regex. [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

```
$str = "aab1230";
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-z]+$/', $str)) {
   // contains only characters [0-9] and/or [a-z]
}
```

Comment: should the modifier be `+` instead of `*`?

Comment: you might want to add `/^` and `$/` so it matches all of the string